# Compare Strings with SSIS expression language

Tags: ssis

SSIS variables -  `strOne = YES, strTwo = YES`. I want to compare strings using ssis expression language (ie inside a variable's expression box, constraint of task flow arrow etc).

Will `@strOne == @strTwo` be true ? I hope its not like programming languages where you need to do `@strOne.Equals(@strTwo)` instead of `==`. Also is `@strOne == "YES"` true ?

Thanks.

Comment: SSIS is case sensite so Yes <> YES and the statement should be @[User::strOne]== @[User::strTwo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will be writing like this. I think you are writing expression for Precedence Constraint.

`@Str1==@Str2` (if they will be equal then your next task will run).